# multiple backbone.js view information in a same underscore.js template not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Backbone view file called searchView.js,I also have a Underscore.js Template called search.templates.html. In the searchView.js I am fetching multiple information from different models in searchView.js e.g: Banner, Search and without search.I want to show multiple information in a same Underscore.js file but I am facing a problem in Underscore template,whenever I am trying to run the template page,tamplate only displays the banner information, Not getting the Search and without search information.I am new in this technology.Please help me anyone.

/searchView.js

```js
var SearchView = BaseView.extend({
  events: {
    "click .serviceDetails": "openServiceDetail"
  },
  constructor: function SearchView() {
    var self = this;
    self.bannerModel = new bannerModel({});
    self.listenTo(Backbone.Events, 'search.controller:render', self.fetchData);
    self.listenTo(Backbone.Events, 'banner:loaded', self.renderBanner);
    BaseView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  renderBanner: function() {
    var self = this;
    var details = self.bannerModel.get('serviceDetails');
    console.log(details);
    var formattedData = {
      name: details[0].VendorAttributeValue,
      overview: details[1].VendorAttributeValue,
      priceAdult: details[2].VendorAttributeValue,
      priceChild: details[3].VendorAttributeValue,
      image: details[4].VendorAttributeValue
    };
    console.log(instaConfig, formattedData);
    self.$el.html(_.template(SearchTpl)({
      instaConfig: instaConfig,
      details: formattedData
    }))
  },
  initialize: function SearchView() {
    var self = this;
    self.searchModel = new searchModel();
    self.searchModel.params = {};

    if (window.q) {
      self.searchModel.setParam('q', window.q);
      self.searchModel.fetch();
      self.listenTo(this.searchModel, 'sync', self.renderSearchParam);
      delete window.q;
    } else {
      self.searchModel.get('searchDetails');
      self.searchModel.fetch();
      self.listenTo(this.searchModel, 'sync', self.renderWithoutSearch);
    }
  },
  renderSearchParam: function() {
    var self = this;
    var dataSearchParam = self.searchModel.get('searchDetails');
    console.log(dataSearchParam);
    var formattedSearchData = {
      name: dataSearchParam[3].serviceShortName,
      price: dataSearchParam[3].ListPrice,
      image: dataSearchParam[3].imageUrl[0]
    }
    console.log(formattedSearchData);
    self.$el.html(_.template(SearchTpl)({
      details: formattedSearchData
    }))
  },
  renderWithoutSearch: function() {
    var self = this;
    var data = self.searchModel.get('searchDetails');
    console.log(data);
    var formattedWithoutSearchData = {
      name: data[0].serviceShortName,
      price: data[0].ListPrice,
      image: data[0].imageUrl
    };
    console.log(formattedWithoutSearchData);
    self.$el.html(_.template(SearchTpl)({
      data: formattedWithoutSearchData
    }))
  },
  openServiceDetail: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate('/1/1/nextStage', {
      "trigger": true,
      replace: false
    });
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
  }
})
```

/search.templates.html

```html
<div class="guest-home-main">
  <header id="book-head" class="serviceDetails" style="background-image: url(<%=instaConfig.vimgurlService%><%=details.image%>)">
    <div class="container" id="banner-view">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center main-text">
          <h1><font color="green">Tour Name: <%=details.name%></font></h1>
          <p><font color="green">Description: <%=details.overview%></font>
          </p>
          <h5><font color="green">Adult Price: INR <%=details.priceAdult%></font></h5>
          <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Book Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End Of Banner Information -->


  <!-- search Information -->


  <section id="recom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour-head">
          <div class="col-md-4 tour_1">
            <div class="tour-box ">
              <a href="">
                <img src="modules/core/assets/dummy/tour-2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
              <div class="disc">
                <div class="sale">Our Best Seller</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tour-det">
                <h5><%=dataSearchParam.name%></h5>
                <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="price" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <%=dataSearchParam.price%><span class="caret"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- End Of Search -->


                <!-- without Search Information -->


                <div class="col-md-4 tour_1">
                  <div class="tour-box">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="modules/core/assets/dummy/tour-6.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                    <div class="tour-det">
                      <h5><%=data.name%></h5>
                      <p>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <div class="price" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                        <%=data.price%> <span class="caret"></span>
                      </div>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu price-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i><%=data.price%></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class="book-head">
                      <div class="b-now serviceDetails">Book Now</div>
                      <div class="add-to">
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="modules/core/assets/dummy/addto.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                        <p>Add to my Tours</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Without Search -->
```

Comment: 2 line breaks between every line makes the code unreadable and creates huge scroll. What is `constructor`? How is it different from `initialize`? Why do you have same named function (`SearchView`) for both of them? Why are you writing `var self = this;` everywhere it is totally unnecessary? All of this is making it hard to read the code and understand it. Please try to sanitize and format the code while posting. If you have bindings like `data.name`, then you always have to pass in `data`. You should have errors in your console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible solution is to wait for all the models (Banner, search & without search) to be fetched using $.when jquery method and consolidate the data from all models before sending it to the template

```
$.when(bannerModel.fetch(), searchModel.fetch()).done(function(model1, model2) {
  /* consolidate all models data */

  self.$el.html(_.template(SearchTpl)({
    bannerData: model1[0],
    searchData: model2[0]
  }))
});
```